# vb.net validate string containing backslahes

Tags: vb.net, string, validation

Say I have the following string:

```
C:\folder1\folder2\ <- this is valid
C:\foler1\folder2 <- this is invalid
C:\folder1\folder2\folder3 <- invalid
```

Basically I want to check that the directory the user enters is in the format

`C:\somthing\somthing\`

anything else is invalid

Best approach? regex? or string functions?

Current vb approach:

```
Private Sub txtboxLocRoot_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)   Handles txtboxLocRoot.Validating

    If txtboxLocRoot.Text.Split("\").Length - 1 <> 3 Then
        MsgBox("Local root must be in the format 'C:\dir1\[folder name]\'", vbExclamation, "Error")
        Return
    End If

    Dim foldernamearray() As String = Split(txtboxLocRoot.Text, "\")
    pfoldername = foldernamearray(2)
    txtboxLocRoot.Text = "C:\dir1\" & pfoldername & "\"

End Sub
```

Comment: Valid as in 'is the string in the correct format' not checking the actual directory exists on the file system

Comment: do you know how to do it with string functions and/or regex and just want advice about which to choose? or do you need help getting started with string functions / regex?

Comment: Having trouble getting a regex to work, I have vb solution which works using split.

Comment: A better approach would be to use the Path class to combine folders and files.  Then you don't need to worry about if the entered path ends with a slash or not.  `txtboxLocRoot.Text = Path.Combine("c:\dir1", pfoldername)`  This will take care of folder separators for you.

Answer (score 1):

To get up and running with some quick and dirty string functions why not something like:

```
If value.StartsWith("c:\") and value.EndsWith("\") then
    'it's starting to look OK
    'do some further testing for a single "\" in the middle section
End If
```

Then also use [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx) and [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) to check there's not rubbish in there.

Comment: Nice, looks a bit more elegant that my current approach

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not elegant, but better error cheking:

***UPDATED***

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim [Directory] As String = "C:\dir1\dir2\"

    If DirectoryValidator([Directory]) Then
        ' Continue...
    Else
        ' Throw
    End If

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Validates a directory path.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Directory">
''' Indicates the directory to validate.
''' </param>
''' <returns><c>true</c> if validated successfully, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
''' <exception cref="Exception">
''' Too less directories.
''' or
''' Too much directories.
''' or
''' Bad syntax.
''' or
''' Missing '\' character.
''' </exception>
Private Function DirectoryValidator(ByVal [Directory] As String) As Boolean

    Select Case [Directory].Contains("\")

        Case True
            If [Directory].StartsWith("C:\", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) AndAlso [Directory].EndsWith("\") Then

                Dim PartsLength As Integer = [Directory].Split({"\"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
                Dim InvalidChars As Char() = IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars

                If PartsLength < 3 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Too less directories.")
                    Return False

                ElseIf PartsLength > 3 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Too much directories.")
                    Return False

                ElseIf (From c As Char In [Directory] Where InvalidChars.Contains(c)).Any Then
                    Throw New Exception("Invalid characters.")
                    Return False

                End If

            Else
                Throw New Exception("Bad syntax.")
                Return False

            End If

        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("Missing '\' character.")
            Return False

    End Select

    Return True

End Function
```